# Unit Test Case for WSO2 Sequences

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am trying to write a Unit test for a sequence by referring to [WSO2 Blog](https://wso2.com/blogs/thesource/how-to-write-effective-unit-testing-using-wso2-integration-studio/) ,  but the blogpost has test case for Proxy-Service which is not relevant.
Is there any way to write a Unit test for only Sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope you are using [Integration Studio](https://wso2.com/integration/integration-studio/) for the development. If so, this will be an easy thing. Please follow the below steps to test a sequence in WSO2 EI.

1. Create a sequence for your solution via the Integration Studio. Here I will use the following sample artifact. Simply, this sequence will create a JSON payload inside the mediation.

```
<sequence name="sample" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>{
            "Hello" : "World"
            }
        </format>
        <args/>
    </payloadFactory>
</sequence>
```

2. Right-click on the sequence and select **New > Unit Test Suite** to create a unit test suite for your sequence.
3. Open the created test-suite file located in `test` directory.
4. Add an assertion to the created test-suite as follows. Here you can use the graphical editor of the Integration Studio.

```
<unit-test>
    <artifacts>
        <test-artifact>
            <artifact>/testConfigs/src/main/synapse-config/sequences/sample.xml</artifact>
        </test-artifact>
        <supportive-artifacts/>
        <registry-resources/>
        <connector-resources/>
    </artifacts>
    <test-cases>
        <test-case name="sampleTest">
            <input/>
            <assertions>
                <assertEquals>
                    <actual>$body</actual>
                    <expected><![CDATA[{
                                "Hello" : "World"
                                }]]>
                    </expected>
                    <message>Actual and Expected are not matched</message>
                </assertEquals>
            </assertions>
        </test-case>
    </test-cases>
    <mock-services/>
</unit-test>
```

5. Then right-click on the test suite and select **Run Unit Test** option.
6. Select either option local or remote to run the test-suite. (For testing purposes use the local option. The Integration Studio will run the unit test with the embedded WSO2 EI server)

You may see the test summary report of the sequence test in the tooling console as below.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] U N I T - T E S T  R E P O R T
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Start Time: 2020-07-29 21:27:47
[INFO] Test Run Duration: 3 seconds
[INFO] Test Summary: 
[INFO] 
[INFO] Test Suite Name: sample.xml
[INFO] ==============================================
[INFO] Pass Test Cases: 1
[INFO] Failure Test Cases: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] +------------------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+
[INFO] |   TEST CASE            |   DEPLOYMENT   |   MEDIATION   |   ASSERTION   |
[INFO] +========================+================+===============+===============+
[INFO] | Test Case - sampleTest |    PASSED      |    PASSED     |    PASSED     |
[INFO] +------------------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Moreover, you can test assert Synapse, Axis2, Transport, $body, $httpVersion, $statusCode expression with this testing framework. Please refer this [documentation](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.1.0/micro-integrator/develop/creating-unit-test-suite/) for more details.

Comment: I had a complex sequence which consisted of multiple internal API Calls, so had to create a mock service and the input here helped to write test cases correctly